# multiple code split points in GWTP presenter

Tags: gwt, gwt-gin

I have a Presenter class which has references to objects of other classes.These objects are large in number roughly 18-25.I have not injected any of the objects. During the GWT compile, this Presenter is converted to a n number of *.cache.js files, out which one cache.js seems to be very large and this file is downloaded when Application starts, making the start up time longer than usual, Is their a way to efficiently use GWT.runAsync() to divide this file into multiple split points?

Thanks in advance

Thanks,

Rohit